# Awk command, print lines which are occurring only once in a csv file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a csv file which may have duplicates. I need help in an awk command which prints only those lines whose occurrence is only once in the file.

Eg:
Input file:

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
a,b
a,c
b,e
b,f
b,d
b,f
b,e
```

Output:

```
a,d
b,d
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{arr[$0]++}END{for(i in arr)if(arr[i]==1)print i}' infile
```

Sort and uniq

```
$ sort file | uniq -u # -u generates unique entries; -d nonunique
a,d
b,d
```

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat file
a,b
a,c
a,d
a,b
a,c
b,e
b,f
b,d
b,f
b,e

$ awk '{arr[$0]++}END{for(i in arr)if(arr[i]==1)print i}' file
a,d
b,d
```

**Explanation:**

- `arr[$0]++` `$0` is current line/record, which is used as array key, `arr` is array, `arr[$0]++` holds a count of occurrence of key, so whenever awk finds duplicate key, count will be incremented by one.
- so at the end block, loop through array, if count is equal to one, print such array key.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest one with **`uniq`** command:

```
uniq -u <(sort file)
```

- `-u` - only print unique lines

The output:

```
a,d
b,d
```

Answer (score 0):

3 method to print the uniq only once blast contigs.

```
awk 'NF>4' valsidate_1k_vs_gdd13|grep Chr|awk '{arr[$1]++}END{for(i in arr)if(arr[i]==1)print i}'  

awk 'NF>4' valsidate_1k_vs_gdd13|grep Chr|cut -f 1|sort| uniq -u

awk 'NF>4' valsidate_1k_vs_gdd13|grep Chr|cut -f 1|sort |uniq -c |grep  '\ 1 Chr'
```